# Image not sending over UDP due to less buffer size C#

Tags: c#, image, sockets, udp

I am sending **Bitmap** image encoded in the form **jpeg** **over UDP socket**.The issue is there is variable size of images each time.**Container** is **Image Packet** which consists of Multiple or Single Image with a packet Identifier Information.

**Server Side**

```
MemoryStream Ms = new MemoryStream();
bformatter.Serialize(Ms, container);
byte[] TestingFlow = Ms.GetBuffer();
ServerSocket.SendTo(TestingFlow, 54000, 
                    SocketFlags.None, RemoteEndpoint);
```

**Client Side**

```
byte[] Recievedbytes = UdpListener.Receive(ref RemoteEndPoint);
ImageStream = new MemoryStream(Recievedbytes, 0, Recievedbytes.Length);
imagecontainer = (ImageContainer)bformater.Deserialize(ImageStream);
```

Comment: Note that you should probably be using `ToArray` rather than `GetBuffer()`, *or* use `Ms.Length` when you send - otherwise you'll probably be sending a load of unnecessary zeroes.

Comment: Should I use ServerSocket.SendTo(Ms.Buffer(),Ms.Length,SocketFlags.None,RemoteEndPoint); ????

Comment: You could, yes. On the other hand, if you're using UDP you'll need to be careful when it comes to large sizes. Do you really want to do any chunking etc yourself?

Comment: AT the moment I am not doing any Chunking.Actually I am frustrated that which mechanism i should adopt??Any Idea

Comment: Well we don't have enough information about *why* you're using UDP to start with. Why not just use TCP which handles this for you?

Comment: Due to latency and Audio Video Synchronization Issue.I have to use RTP (Real Time Transport Protocol) under the umbrella of UDP.That are the main reasons which let me to use UDP

Comment: Then you'll need to work out how to handle missing packets, how to chunk things etc.

Comment: Do you have any clue how can i initiate the handling process?

Comment: Not really - it sounds like you're following an existing protocol, so you need to look at what that says to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you have to use

```
ServerSocket.SendTo(TestingFlow,TestingFlow.Length,
                    SocketFlags.None, RemoteEndpoint);
```

in server side

Comment: The Array size is very much bigger above 100KB..What i would have to do then??

Comment: @Samie: does the error occur the first time you run your code (server side)? You (IMO) should send your file in little chunks until you get full size...

Comment: @Macro:Actually the mechanism was previously on TCP.In TCP when I get the Image Packet I just Serialize it On **NetworkStream** using **Binary Formatters** and on Client Side I just Call TCP.GetStream to get the NS and deserialize to get back images.There exist no issue in that case.Now I can't fragments the image packets as I have to render it on Client..If fragmentation is possible!!Would you please tell me how it could be done??

Answer (score 0):

UDP for sending an image file? No way.

If you're after data integrity then forget it. TCP is the better protocol.

UDP is for sending small data packets where speed is the issue rather than data integrity, hence its use in internet gaming. Datagrams may arrive out of order, be duplicated, or vanish completely. UDP has no intrinsic error checking or correction. This is left to the application if required. Hence its speed over reliability.

Unless you wish to write all of that error checking with resend requests and datagram handling (to ensure that you build your file back up in the right order) then just use TCP over sockets.

At least with TCP you can split your image up into manageable blocks, send them and be safe in the knowledge that they'll arrive in the right order and complete.

Comment: I am using UDP for fast communication.Minor Jitters due to Communication overheads are negligible.The main concern is speed that is why I am transforming Already TCP based communication mechanism to UDP

Comment: I would suggest that you increase your jpeg compression then to bring the image size down.

Comment: I am already compressing It using Deflating Stream algorithm but the size can't be significantly reduced